# C++ - ExpandEnvironmentStrings Giving Conversion Error

Tags: c++

I have been using this:

```
char appdata[250];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%\\\MCPCModLocator\\", appdata, 250);
```

in C++ Win32 to get the AppData folder on one of my projects. Its worked fine, no issues. Now on my newest project (same PC, still in Visual Studio 2013) when I try to do that, i get an error on the first string saying "const char* is incompatible with type LPCWSTR" and on the second parameter it says "char * is incompatible with type LPWSTR". I have no idea why it work on the first project, but not the second. I assume its a setting change, but looking through each projects settings, I see nothing. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Don't hardcode the `250`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, newly created project in VS2013 has been set to use Unicode APIs, those use LPWSTR (or, wchar_t*) instead of LPSTR(or, char*).

You can call the old ANSI version APIs by add "A" at the end of function name explicitly e.g. ExpandEnvironmentStringsA or change the project configuration to use Multibyte character set(Project Property pages -> configuration properties -> general -> character set)

Comment: @dogger20011 To work with old code, I think changing configuration to using ANSI API costs less labor. But I personally recommend unicode-style APIs for newly written code (or, using TEXT macro to adapt literal string to both ANSI and UNICODE APIs. But be aware that some APIs has no ANSI style). By the way, CT2A(EX) and CT2W(EX) macro can be used to convert between unicode and ansi strings if ATL is used in your project, or WideCharToMultiByte and MultiByteToWideChar if ATL is not used in your project.

Answer (score 5):

`ExpandEnvironmentStrings` is a macro that expands to `ExpandEnvironmentStringsA` or `ExpandEnvironmentStringsW` depending on whether `UNICODE` was defined when you included `<windows.h>`.

In a Visual Studio project `UNICODE` is defined by default, but this is not so for command line use of the compiler.

Since modern Windows programming is better based on Unicode, the best fix is not to remove the definition of `UNICODE` but to add an `L` prefix to your literals, like `L"Hello"`, which makes it a “wide” `wchar_t` based literal, and correspondingly change the type of `appdata`.